# The continuous dual of the reals

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I just have a few questions involving the continuous dual of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. We know that the dual $(\mathbb{R}^{N})^{*}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is the space of all linear forms $$a: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{  } \text{ such that } x \mapsto \langle a,x \rangle$$   Consider the mapping $\pi: (\mathbb{R}^{N})^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$ defined as
$$\langle a,x \rangle = (\pi a,x ) \text{  }\text{ where }a \in (\mathbb{R}^{N})^{*}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the scalar product.
If we have are given a function $$F: \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{N})^{*}$$

then it follows that $$\langle F(x),y \rangle = (\pi F(x),y) = \sum_{j}F_{j}(x)y_{j}$$

1. I want to show that if the functions $F_{1}(x),...,F_{N}(x)$ are continuous then $F$ is continuous. Is the following proof fine:

Take $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. Then since each of $F_{1}(x_{n}) \rightarrow F_{1}(x)...F_{N}(x_{n}) \rightarrow F_{n}(x)$ it follows that $\langle F(x_{N}),y \rangle \rightarrow \langle F(x),y \rangle$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. Therefore we have that $F(x_{n}) \rightharpoonup^{*} F(x)$(weak star convergence) and since $(R^{N})^{*}$ is finite-dimensional, this is the same as $F(x_{n}) \rightarrow F(x)$. This shows that $F$ is continuous. Firstly is this proof fine and secondly is there a better way to show continuity?

2.What are the properties that defines the mapping $\pi: (\mathbb{R}^{N})^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}$? I suspect that it is at least linear and bijective but I think by the Ries-representation theorem it follows that it is even an isometry?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It follows from the fact that a linear operator is [bounded iff it is continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator). Since each $F_j$ is bounded, we have that $F$ is bounded.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Okay but is my proof fine also?

Comment: I believe so. Also, the map $\pi$ is also an isometry; this follows, as you say, from the Riesz representation theorem. It is often called the Riesz--Fréchet theorem, as there are several Riesz representation theorems.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Could you explain how each $F_{j}$ bounded implies that $F$ is bounded.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/839838/139960. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Okay will do, thanks.

Comment: @AlexSchiff I have one other question related to the proof of the Riesz-representation theorem. The proof starts with $T: H \rightarrow H^{*}$ such that $\langle Tf,u \rangle = (f,u)$ for all $u \in H$. It then says that $\Vert Tf \Vert_{H^{*}} = |f|$. Do you know how to prove this?

Comment: See [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/ottobre/fa/riesz-frechet.pdf) for an explanation as to why $\|Tf\|_{H^*}=\|f\|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is as defined in the OP, let $M=\max{\{\|F_j\|\}}$. Since all norms on $\Bbb R$ are equivalent, take $\|x\|:=\sum\limits_j|x_j|$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
\|F\|&=\sup{\{\|F(x)\|\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\}}=\sup{\left\{\sup{\{|\left<F(x),y\right>|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&=\sup{\left\{\sup{\left\{\left|\sum_jF_j(x)y_j\right|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\right\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&\leq\sup{\left\{\sup{\left\{\sum_j\left|F_j(x)y_j\right|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\right\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&\leq\sup{\left\{\sup{\left\{\sum_j(\|F_j\|)(\|x\|)\left|y_j\right|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\right\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&\leq\sup{\left\{\sup{\left\{M\|x\|\sum_j\left|y_j\right|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\right\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&=\sup{\left\{M\|x\|\cdot\sup{\left\{\|y\|\,\mid\,0\leq \|y\|\leq 1\right\}}\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\right\}}\\
&=M\sup{\{\|x\|\,\mid\,0\leq \|x\|\leq 1\}}=M.
\end{align*}
So we have that $F$ is bounded and hence continuous.